# Views 2 Drupal 6 Filter Result if none of the fields have a value

Tags: 6, views, panels

What I need seems pretty straightforward but I cannot seem to accomplish it.

I have a view, a content pane to be precise, fetching specific fields of the node that it's parent panel overrides.

What I need, is for the view to return 0 results (and thus be hidden completely) if NONE of the fields are populated. If even one fields is populated I want it to display, but if NONE of the fields in question have a value I need the content pane to dissapear completely. I understand I have to do it with filtering and the NOT NULL option but I cannot understand how since in 2.x-6.x there is no AND/OR capability of what I can see.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module [Views Or](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_or) allows me to add OR clauses to my filters and get the job done. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... allows [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to combine filters or arguments with OR and fields with COALESCE.